# Value of String Variable Doesn't Change

Tags: c#, variables

I have downloaded a string representation of a stock value (Via Yahoo finance API). However when I try to assign the the value to a String variable, it retains it's previous value and doesn't change. Here's the code.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    String result = "Default";

    public void wb_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        result = e.Result;

        //I changed the application title to be sure the required string was in fact downloaded
        ApplicationTitle.Text = e.Result;
    }

    //When I Click a radio button, the tile is created and inialized
    private void radioButton1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wb = new WebClient();
        wb.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=a"));
        wb.DownloadStringCompleted += wb_DownloadStringCompleted;

        //string result = DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs.result;
        int newCount = 0;

        // Application Tile is always the first Tile, even if it is not pinned to Start.
        ShellTile TileToFind = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

        // Application should always be found
        if (TileToFind != null)
        {
            // Set the properties to update for the Application Tile.
            // Empty strings for the text values and URIs will result in the property being cleared.
            StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
            {
                Title = "Stocks",
                BackgroundImage = new Uri("google_icon.jpg", UriKind.Relative),
                Count = newCount,
                BackTitle = "Google Stock",
                BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("google_icon.jpg", UriKind.Relative),

                //This is where the problem is. The value of result is still "Default"
                BackContent = result.ToString()
            };

            // Update the Application Tile
            TileToFind.Update(NewTileData);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to display the result in a live tile and it shows the value "Default" instead of the stock value "548.47"

Comment: check e.Result , what is the value of e.result

Comment: What happens after `wb_DownloadStringCompleted` finishes? I suspect the page/whatever is refreshed and the value in `result` reset to `"Default"`

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years. The value of e.result is 548.47. I confirmed by setting the value of a textBlock (ApplicationTitle in this case) with it.

Comment: Can you show the code for live tile updating?

Comment: after result = e.Result; , try MessageBox.Show(result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your live tiles *after* the download has finished - in other words, from within the `wb_DownloadStringCompleted` handler.

```
public void wb_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //this can probably be a local variable
    result = e.Result;

    //update live tile here.
}
```

Your current code is launching an async task and then update the tile right away. Because the task hasn't finished yet, `result` is still set to the default value.